# Best practice for Django components

Tags: django

Django provides a means of collecting assets into its Widget framework, and in turn using a form to present it, but how about doing this outside the forms framework?

For example, let's say I just want a simple, self-enclosed web component that requires two .js files, a CSS file, a template, and is backed by a view to generate some data.  This isn't a "form" because it's not intended to collect input. Rather, assume it's, say, a customized scrollbar.  I can't seem to find the right match for this usage pattern even though it seems common and straight-forward.

To do this now seems to mean adding the CSS to the top-level template; the JS to the template (or script tags arbitrarily in the included document); and then rendering the form as an include.  But wouldn't it be easier to have something like:

```
class ScrollBar(...):
    template_name = ...

    class Assets:
        ...
```

and then rendering it via a templatetag, but with the ability for a context processor or other hook to extract the assets into their appropriate places in the page?

Something like:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    {% compressed_css %}
</head>
<body>
    ...
    {% compressed_js %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

scrollbar-using-page.html

```
{% extends "index" %}
{% block content %}
{% scrollbar args %}
{% endblock %}
```

with the end result being the scrollbar's template is rendered with the specified args, and its JS and CSS are merged into the compressed_css and compressed_js areas, respectively, above?

I think we get there almost 100% via this approach, without the compressed_js/compressed_css sections, which raises the question of whether then we just included these in all shared pages.  (Alternatively, we could use nested/inherited blocks.)

Adam